# React state data not showing on first component render

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js

Here is my code I'm looking to get followers data from `Firestore` and then fetching users from doc id but I'm getting data in the console log but data not showing on the first time component render but when I click the tab for the second time it renders data and correct followers users showing can someone tell me what I am doing wrong ?

```
export default function RequestTab() {

    const [followers, setfollowers] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (firebase.auth().currentUser) {
            let data = [];
            db.collection("buddiez")
                .where("followeeId", "==", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
                .where("accepted", "==", false)
                .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
                    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                        db.collection("users").doc(doc.data().followerId).get().then((result) => {
                            data.push({ ...result.data() })
                        });
                    });
                });
            setfollowers(data)
        }
    }, [])

    console.log(followers);

    let userArr = followers ? followers.map((follower, i) => {
        return <div key={i} className="request-details pb-3 border-bottom">
            <div className="noty-usepf-icon">
                <img className="rounded-circle mt-0" style={{ width: "45px", height: "45px" }} src={follower.profilePic ? follower.profilePic : ""} alt="" />
            </div>
            <div className="request-info">
                <h3 className="mb-n1" style={{ fontSize: '1.1rem' }}>{follower.fullName}</h3>
                <span>@{follower.username}</span>
            </div>
            <div className="accept-feat">
                <ul>
                    <li><button type="submit" className="accept-req">Accept</button></li>
                    <li><button type="submit" className="close-req"><i className="la la-close" /></button></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    }) : <h2 className="text-muted p-3 d-flex justify-content-center">No Requests !</h2>

    return (
        <div className="tab-pane show active">
            <div className="acc-setting">
                <h3>Requests</h3>
                <div className="requests-list">
                    {userArr}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: You're not taking into account that it's an async call and the call will essentially *always* take longer than the first render. Code appropriately.

Comment: I tried few things but still not getting the desired result please can you show me how to do it...@DaveNewton

Comment: Handle a render when the data isn't there yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot man for your help... I just set a isFetching state and make it true when the data is fetched and then render it... @DaveNewton

Answer (score 0):

I assume Following code `db.collection("users").doc(doc.data().followerId).get()` is async, so `setfollowers(data)` will happen before these promises are resolved, so data will be empty, you have to wait until all promises are resolved and then set state, you can use Promise.All for this case.